# Which is better to rebuild stackoverflow, CouchDB or MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

If we would try to create a similar site like stackoverflow (this site), what is your preference between the CouchDB and MongoDB? why?

I guess this site seems need only pre-defined queries, and data is accumulated, when we want a master-master replication, couchDB seems to be a better choice.

but from performance point of view, mongo seems better.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively I think couchdb. It's easier to replicate. And that's important if you want to scale... as you already guessed.